# Задача по книге “A byte of Python” - адресная книга. Новый код

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ключ и значение сохраняются только Book.data, но не в сам словарь. Почему так происходит? Я же вроде открыл файл для записи и поместил это в init - ведь эта же функция нужна для инициализации (т.е. для произведения некоторых действий при первоначальной загрузке), но запись всё равно происходит только в Book.data. Почему подскажите. Я перечитал опять главу ООП по этой же книге "A byte of Python" и и нового там ничего не нашёл. Может что-то я упустил в этой главе?

```
import pickle


class Address:
    my_dict = dict()

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

        Address.my_dict = dict()
        with open('booking.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write(key)
            file.write(value)

        file.close()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.key = input('Введите имя: ')
        self.value = input('Введите адрес: ')
        Address.my_dict[self.key] = self.value
        if self.key in Address.my_dict:
            print('\nАдрес:', Address.my_dict)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        self.key = input('Введите имя для удаления: ')
        del Address.my_dict[self.key]
        print('\nВ адресной книге: {0} 
контактов\n'.format(len(Address.my_dict)))
        for name, address in Address.my_dict.items():
            print('\nКонтакт: {0}, с адресом {1}.'.format(name, 
address))

    def change(self):
        self.key = input('Введите имя которое нужно изменить: ')
        del Address.my_dict[self.key]

        self.fname = input('Введите новое имя: ')
        self.semail = input('Введите новый адрес: ')
        Address.my_dict[self.fname] = self.semail
        if self.fname in Address.my_dict:
            print('\nАдрес:', Address.my_dict)

    def find(self):
        self.key = input('Введите имя для поиска: ')
        if self.key in Address.my_dict:
            print('Адрес: ', Address.my_dict[self.key])

        if self.key is not Address.my_dict:
            print('Такого имени не найдено.')

    def loading():
        file = open('Book.data', 'rb')
        pickle.load(file)  # Помещаем объект в файл.
        file.close()

    loading = staticmethod(loading)

    def store():
        file = open('Book.data', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(Address.my_dict, file)  # Помещаем объект в файл.
        file.close()

     store = staticmethod(store)


r = Address('', '')
Address.loading()
running = True
while running:
    search = int(input('Введите - 1-Добавить контакт; 2-Удалить 
контакт;\
 3-Изменить контакт; 4-Найти контакт;\
 Для выхода их программы введите 5-Выход: '))
    if search == 1:
        r.__setitem__('', '')
        if len(Address.my_dict) == 100:
            print('Адресная книга переполнена, удалите 1 из контактов')
            r.__delitem__('')

    if search == 2:
        r.__delitem__('')
        Address.store()

    if search == 3:
        r.change()
        Address.store()

    if search == 4:
        r.find()

    if search == 5:
        Address.store()
        running = False

    if len(Address.my_dict) == 0:
        running = False
```

Comment: А сам словарь это booking.txt?

Comment: Нет конечно, но даже если я изменяю его на my_dict.txt - по прежнему та же проблема.

Comment: А как вы определили что нет сохранения в словарь?

Comment: Ну во-первых: начинаю поиск по словарю после закрытия проги - вывод, что нет такого имени. Во-вторых: при открытии самого файла в PyCharm - опять же нет такого имени и  значения.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка вот в чем

```
def loading():
        file = open('Book.data', 'rb')
        pickle.load(file)  # Помещаем объект в файл.
        file.close()
```

Вы загружаете данные, но никуда их не записываете.
Вот так буде правильно

```
 Address.my_dict=pickle.load(file)  # Помещаем объект в файл.
```

Comment: Спасибо. Получилось теперь поиск выполняется. Но теперь ещё вопрос: почему не записывается в сам документ. Я имею ввиду когда открываешь напрямую документ через PyCharm или ищешь на компьютере?

Comment: Потому что вы пишете в бинарный файл. Там есть данные. Файл находится там же где исходный текст вашей программы.

Comment: Да уж, а я голову ломал. Я писал вместо этой переменной обычную - без обращения к классу и мне выдавало ошибку, вот я убрал вообще. Называется "а ларчик просто открывался". Теперь буду работать над исключениями. Огромное спасибо.